# GDB Conditional breakpoint, Weird Behaviour

Tags: c++, gdb

GDB Version: 8.1

The following, does not work:

```
condition 2 strcmp(x,"hello") == 0
```

The following, works

```
condition 2 strcmp()(x,"hello") == 0
```

why?

Comment: As an alternative, you can use the [convenience function](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html) `$_streq(x, "hello")` which will return 1 if they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

> why?

Assuming you are on a Linux system, this is most likely caused by the fact that `strcmp` is a [GNU indirect function](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC).

Installing debug info for GLIBC (`libc-dbg`, or some such package) may help.

This could be a considered a bug in GDB, feel free to create a new [bugzilla](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb) issue for it.